# regex by using "." to take one character

Tags: python

I wish to take a character infront of the digit. sometimes there is no character infront of the digit. Is there a way to do so?

My problem is by using my regex pattern, it will take the pattern if there is a character infront of the digit but when there is no character infront then it cant take.

```
import re
a = "got1%"
temp = re.findall("(.\d+.)", a)
```

current output:

```
['t1%']
```

when I change my input "a = "1%""

The output become:

```
[]
```

my expected output is:

```
['1%']
```

I wish to have a pattern that can process both of these cases.

Comment: If i remove it then it wont take the "t". What I wanted is to be able to process both cases.

Comment: You can specify how many times the "dot" can repeat: `(.?\d+.)`

Comment: when t present then it will take and when it does not then it just return the value like i expect.

Comment: forcebru Can I know what do you mean? I still dont understand

Comment: thank you forcebru! it worked like magic.

Comment: `.?` means "whatever `.` is, it may be repeated zero or one times"